# Plotting of data points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy array like,

```
arr=np.array(([1,4],[2,8],[2,9],[2,3],[1,6],[2,5],[1,12],[1,14],[2,3]))
```

How can I plot the data points of the numpy array?

When I doing it like follows;

```
pyplot.plot(arr)
```

it simply plots straight lines only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scatter plot

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr=np.array(([1,4],[2,8],[2,9],[2,3],[1,6],[2,5],[1,12],[1,14],[2,3]))

plt.scatter(arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
plt.show()
```